# intelliJ shows Bootstrap classes as typos

Tags: intellij-idea

I just created a new static web project using the Bootstrap template. In my html files it is marking the names of Bootstrap css classes as typos. Surely the worlds smartest IDE is better than that? How do I make it aware of Bootstrap classes? I know I can disable spell checking but that seems like an awful solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow [WI-4762](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-4762) for updates to be notified on any progress with it. For now, I can only suggest to either disable the spell checker or add the words shown as typos to dictionary